# What do PhD programs, specifically finance and Econ programs, look for in research experience?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I believe I have the pre-requisite GPA, GRE, tough classes, etc. to get in to a top PhD program in finance or economics. What I believe I am missing is the research experience.

What are these top programs looking for in the research arena, it's not exactly listed on their sites?

Is faculty supervised research experience a must have for a top 10 program? Or will independent research suffice?

If you have basically perfect attributes in the other metrics, does research experience matter too much?

Comment: This might be a bit dated, but research experience used to be absolutely not required. If you had some, cool; if not, you're hired on promise (gaged from alma mater, GPA, GRE, recommendations and such). From memory, we had 11 across these two fields in my first year. In finance, one had a Ph.D. in physics; in econ, one had done genuine Econ research. That leaves, say, 8 or 9 out of 11 w/o any relevant experience (including me). That said, these two are now by far the most accomplished researchers. Coincidence? I don't know.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what year did you start your PhD?

Comment: More relevantly, I graduated in 2002. By then, it was still like this.

Answer (score 1):

This probably depends a lot on your definition of "top."

To get a sense for what successful applicants look like, check the websites, CVs, and/or LinkedIn profiles of current students in the programs you are interested in. (Look at their history from before they entered the program, of course.)

For example, I looked up the list of [current econ PhD students at NYU Stern](http://www.stern.nyu.edu/experience-stern/about/departments-centers-initiatives/academic-departments/economics/academic-programs/phd/current-students) and started Googling. All the ones I checked (the first five names or so currently on that list) had some kind of formal research experience prior to joining the program.